# How to run a command from anywhere in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, conversion, path, environment-variables

I need to use a command for converting my images to pvrtc. It is located in */Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool*.

Right now I have to be inside that folder to be able to use the command. How can I set it up so I can run this command from anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can run it from everywhere by just typing

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool [options here]
```

at the commandline.

But it is easier to add the folder to your PATH. For this, edit the `.bash_profile` in your home directory and add the lines:

```
# Including developer tools
PATH="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This has the advantage that every executable in `/Developer/.../usr/bin` is available by just typing the name.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to tweak your search PATH, define an `alias` in your profile

Answer (score 0):

You can call it directly with an absolute path:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool
```